# With Azure Functions with Flask, How I can implement 2 Azure function webhook to simultaneously run from console

Tags: azure, function

How to actively create webhook links through ngrok / any other services from Azure Function applications.

I am in need of 2 different function(), one function programmed to run all the time.
And another when I perform respective event at my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to create a web hook the calls a single function.

That function would then call your 2 functions, the first every time and the second when conditions are met.

Comment: OK. Its cool. But When both services need the functions to run simultaneously, how it is achievable. I found few solution with threading concepts may help and run concurrently both the function once the webhook trigger is made. In My case: The active webhook link is not getting trigger when I called from other services.